# Windows Phone 8.1 Hijri Calendar

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How can I covert winrt xaml toolkit calendar Georgian format to Hijri Calendar Is there any way ? Please  please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can covert a date to Hijri calendar.

```
using System.Globalization;

CultureInfo arSA = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; //Get from your toolkit calendar
lblLog.Text = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", arSA);
```

Hope this helps.